# My Android App code is exposing plain text data in Android RAM which an Attacker can steal

Tags: javascript, android, memory-leaks, android-security

A security tester has reported a Bug. According to them, An attacker can attach a debugger and dump the memory from the application, or load a kernel module to dump the entire contents of RAM."

```
@JavascriptInterface
    fun getCustomerData(): String {
        return eTestWebViewViewModel.getCustomerDataJson(customer)
    }
```

I read multiple blogs and tried to analyse the issue. But, I am not able to find any solution.

Plain text:

```
{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","age":25,"address":{"streetAddress":"21 2nd Street","city":"New York","state":"NY","postalCode":"10021"},"phoneNumber":[{"type":"home","number":"212 555-1234"},{"type":"fax","number":"646 555-4567"}]}
```

Comment: There generally is no "solution" for this "issue", insofar as nearly every computer program created in human history has this "bug". For short-lived pieces of data (such as passphrases) in apps where users are at risk of this attack (so-called "nation-state-level adversaries"), there are some techniques that you can use. But, in general, a computer program needs to have access to the data that the program uses, and *very* few people are likely to have their phone subjected to this sort of attack.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can I encrypt these data while passing to the webview and decrypt the same on the end ?

Comment: That does not solve any actual problems. The memory of the `WebView` can be dumped using the same technique that your security researcher mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try detecting memory debug
like when someone dump your application memory the file

```
proc/self/mem
```

is triggered and also if attacker dumps the native strings etc then

```
proc/self/maps
```

file will be triggered , attacker will find the target lib starting addr from maps to manipulate that and after that will goto mem for getting runtime memory, i suggest you to use inotify and detect trigger to maps and mem and for good one you can also add inotify for

```
proc/self/cmdline
```

attackers reads that to find the target process pid

Hope It Helps!